# Is exposing client secret a threat for implicit grant type in oauth 2?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have an application which needs to implement oauth 2 for securing rest API. The simple flow will be when a user logs in they should have access to some protected resources ( as per their role).

I will be using angular 7 as front end.

as per this diagram I need to use implicit grant for Single Page Applications. [image]
 now i went on to search and found https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-oauth2-angular

```
API Name - Login
Method - POST
URL - oauth/login
Header - 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('devglan-client:devglan-secret')
Body - {'username' :'admin ',
      'password' :'admin',
    'grant_type':  'password' }
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Now my only concern in this approach is.

i. why this client id and client secret are revealed in angular code ? is client secret not supposed to be kept secret ?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need any secret key to implement the implicit grant flow in the js applications.

You can see the following http url sample which needs few things such as client_id, redirect_uri etc.

We will get the access token in the url fragment of the redirect_uri, and this token authenticates you to access protected resources. However, scope parameter also plays an important to determine resources and its entitlements.

Http Request URI

```
https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/authorize?
  audience=YOUR_API_AUDIENCE&
  scope=YOUR_SCOPE&
  response_type=YOUR_RESPONSE_TYPE&
  client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
  redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback&
  nonce=YOUR_CRYPTOGRAPHIC_NONCE&
  state=YOUR_OPAQUE_VALUE
```

I will highly suggest to go with Authorization Code Grant with PKCE even for the js applications because the access token is vulnerable to various security risks. With PKCE, the attacker needs to solve the puzzle (code challenge) in order to get the access token.

Comment: are you talking about something like openid and okta ?